# buscar en datagridview con un textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

chicos tengo el siguiente problema: debo buscar en una columna de datagridview si el valor de un textbox esta en alguna de las filas de esa columna, si el valor coinicde, me debe mostrar un mensaje que la hora esta ocupada, caso contrario, me desbloquea unos controles y botones. En teoria funciona, pero me di cuenta que siempre funciona con la primer celda que selecciono, con las otras falla la validacion...tengo el siguiente codigo que ejecuto en el evento click de un boton:

```
        private void comparando()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvHorasAtencion.Rows)
        {

            string horaAtencion = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["hora"].Value);

            if (this.textBox1.Text != horaAtencion)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("UPS, LA HORA ESTA OCUPADA");
                hora = "";
                this.label18.Visible = true;
                this.label1.Visible = false;
                return;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DESBLOQUEA TODO, HORA LIBRE");
                this.isNuevo = true;
                this.isEditar = false;
                this.botones();
                this.limpiarControlesInsert();
                this.habilitarControles(true);
                groupBox2.Enabled = true;
                this.label1.Visible = true;
                this.label18.Visible=false;
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

Alguien nota alguna falla?

Saludos a todos, atento a sus comentarios

Comment: Claro. Pase lo que pase en la comparación, ejecutas un return.

Comment: hola @Pikoh, sin el return no hace ni la validacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema de lógica.
Al tener un return en el if y otro en el else siempre se sale en la primera iteracion del foreach

```
private void comparando()
        {
            string message = "UPS, LA HORA ESTA OCUPADA";
            bool encontrado = false;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvHorasAtencion.Rows)
            {

                string horaAtencion = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["hora"].Value);

                if (this.textBox1.Text == horaAtencion) 
                {
                    encontrado = true;
                    message = "DESBLOQUEA TODO, HORA LIBRE";
                    break;



                }
            }


            MessageBox.Show(message);
            if (!encontrado)
            {
                hora = "";
                this.label18.Visible = true;
                this.label1.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.isNuevo = true;
                this.isEditar = false;
                this.botones();
                this.limpiarControlesInsert();
                this.habilitarControles(true);
                groupBox2.Enabled = true;
                this.label1.Visible = true;
                this.label18.Visible = false;


            }
        }
```

Comment: gracias @ElGerar funciono!

Comment: no, no me funciono xD, falsa alarma...

Comment: Puedes dar más detalles de que es lo  q no funcionó?

Comment: solo funciona si pincho en la primer celda del datagridview, si selecciono la fila 3 por ejemplo, no funciona

Comment: El código que tienes mira en todas las filas del `datagrid` en la celda **Hora** por lo que no debería influir en ese error.¿ Que evento usas para realizar la comprobación (el que llama a esta función)?